# Проблема с heroku

Tags: javascript, git, cmd, heroku

Пытаюсь выставить приложение на сервер `heroku`,но не получается,делаю всё как по инструкции

Install the Heroku CLI
Download and install the Heroku CLI.

If you haven't already, log in to your Heroku account and follow the prompts to create a new SSH public key.

```
$ heroku login
```

Create a new Git repository
Initialize a git repository in a new or existing directory

```
$ cd my-project/
$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a name
```

Deploy your application
Commit your code to the repository and deploy it to Heroku using Git.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

Existing Git repository
For existing repositories, simply add the heroku remote

```
$ heroku git:remote -a name
```

После ввода команды

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Выходит ошибка

```
 c:\Games\discord>git push heroku master    Counting objects: 323, done.
    Compressing objects: 100% (312/312), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (323/323), 360.29 KiB | 922.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 323 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote:  !     No default language could be detected for this app.
    remote:                         HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect 
    the
    buildpack to use for this application automatically.
    remote:                         See 
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildp
    acks
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to name.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/name.git
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/name.git'
```

Красным подчеркнута только ошибка что ниже

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/name.git'
```

Пытался делать pull перед push как советовал гугл,но это не особло помогло
И если поможет,то на сайте https://git.heroku.com/name.git только надпись Method Not Allowed

Comment: Как решили данную проблему? Никак не могу её побороть...

Comment: Вы просто скопировали текст из туториала? Вместо `name` должно быть уникальное имя вашего репозитория.